# Выход из аккаунта

Tags: php, mysql, авторизация

Есть статья с готовым кодом для регистрации и авторизации аккаунта: https://htmlweb.ru/php/example/avtorizacija2.php

Но как сделать нормальный выход?

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mysql", "mysql", "mysql");
    $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT user_id, user_password FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['login'])."' LIMIT 1");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    setcookie("id", $data['user_id'], time() - 60*60*24*30);
    setcookie("hash", "", time() - 3600*24*30*12, "/");

    header("Location: index.php"); exit();
?>
```

Я сделал так exit.php, но для одного аккаунта это работает. Если же зарегистрировать новый и пробовать в него зайти, то будет ошибка. Я думаю что это из-за не удаленных нормально cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать сессии

Кусочек вашего кода с авторизацией будет выглядеть так:

```
<?php

session_start();

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mysql", "mysql", "mysql");
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT user_id, user_password FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['login'])."' LIMIT 1");
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

$_SESSION["user_id"] = $data['user_id'];

header("Location: index.php"); exit();
?>
```

Обратите внимание что хеш уже хранить не требуется: данные сессий физически хранятся на сервере, клиенту недоступны и подменить он их не может.

Пример "выхода":

```
<?php

session_start();

unset($_SESSION["user_id"]);

?>
```

Дополнительно рекомендую изучить http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php